# How to create an "offline mode" in a cordova application?

Tags: database, offline

I have to develop an application for tablet (Android).
This application will be used by some people in differents places where an internet connection will not always be available.

But this application needs data to work.
The users will have to be able to use the functionality with and without and internet access.

We will work with cordova to build the application, and we will use the extjs framework.

My question is : how to make a kind of "offline mode" in a cordova application ?
Maybe we have to create a "synchronization" button in the application.
After a first synchronization which save data in a file stored in the device, the user could use the application with this file.
When he open the application without internet access, the data would be loaded from this file.
When the user modify/add/delete some data without internet, we thought add these information in a js file (JSON) which would be sent to the controller which used for synchronisation when internet is back.

But we don't know if this solution is correct or not, and if we can write or read a file stored in the device.

Thanks guys, have a good day.

Comment: I think you have the right idea. I would suggest taking a look at Pouch DB https://pouchdb.com/ as it sounds similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Jack Is Pouch DB can work with a real database using multiple links between tables ?

Comment: You should use SQLLite to store your datas and send them on synchronization

Comment: https://pouchdb.com/adapters.html Pouch DB can be configured to use SQLLite, so it can work with a relational DB